# Store Django Log messages in a database?

Tags: django, logging

Django (the python web framework) uses python's logging system to store logs.

Is there an easy way to store log messages in a database, and then allow admin users to look over them via the web? It's the sort of thing I could write myself, but no point re-inventing the wheel. I don't want to log exceptions, but info/debug/notice type messages that I have added to the code.

Ideally I'd like to be able to store metadata about the log message as it's done (like the remote IP address, user agent, wsgi process id, etc.), and then filter / browse based on that (i.e. show me all log messages from this IP address in the last 24 hours). Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 14):

Just use [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/for/django/). [Raven](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python), the Django piece of the functionality hooks into the logging framework, so in addition to collecting errors from your app, any custom log messages should show up as well.

Comment: Even though I like sentry etc., it doesn't answer the question. I'm interested in a db logger handler. Anyone?

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, but I found that Sentry doesn't exactly replaces logging. See https://sentry.io/vs/logging/ "Sentry doesn't make guarantees of allowing you to find an exact historical error. Because of this, it's important that in cases where you do need to be able to trace events you maintain them in your existing logging infrastructure."

Answer (score 10):

Apart from the obvious choice of Sentry, for the sake of exercise, there is a nice blog article titled "[Creating custom log handler that logs to database models in django](http://james.lin.net.nz/2012/09/19/creating-custom-log-handler-that-logs-to-database-models-in-django/)" in the "James Lin Blog", which briefly explains how to do this using a second database, with code samples.

The code is adapted from the standard Python RotatingFileHandler:

> ...The RotatingFileHandler allows you to specify which file to write to and rotate files, therefore my DBHandler should also allow you to specify which model to insert to and specify expiry in settings, and best of all, on a standalone app.

This could also be easily adapted for using a single db.

Comment: PS. Not including the code itself here on purpose, let me know if it would be desired to do so.

Answer (score 7):

check django-db-logger

it takes less than a minute to integrate

https://github.com/CiCiUi/django-db-logger

Comment: This is amazing and minmalist

Comment: it work similar to Sentry.

Answer (score 1):

try django-requests. I've tried it and it basically just puts the request logs in a table called requests.

Comment: Link? I found a "django-request". https://pypi.org/project/django-request/

Comment: Better link: https://github.com/django-request/django-request

Answer (score 0):

You can check a good solution that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314307/python-logging-to-database/67305494#67305494). You just need a string-connection to connect to your database. For example, if you use a MySQL, the connection-string should be:

```
# mysqlclient
'mysql+mysqldb://username:password@host:port/database'
```

or

```
# PyMySQL
'mysql+pymysql://username:password@host:port/database')
```

then you can use [PhpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) as a "MySQL web administration tool" to look over the database via web browsers or [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) (my preference) to access any database remotely.

---

for using the handler in Django you just need to add the handler class to the LOGGING variable of setting.py as follow:

```
level = 'INFO' if DEBUG else 'WARNING'  # I prefer INFO in debugging mode and WARNING in production
handler = ['log_db_handler', ]  # In production I rarely check the server to see console logs
if DEBUG:
    handler.append('console')

LOGGING = {'version': 1,
           'disable_existing_loggers': False,

           'formatters': {'verbose': {'format': '{levelname} {message}',  # {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d}
                                      'style': '{', }, },

           'handlers': {'log_db_handler': {'level': level,
                                           'class': 'db_logger.handlers.DBHandler',
                                           'formatter': 'verbose', },
                        'console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', }},

           'loggers': {'db_log': {'handlers': handler,
                                  'level': level,
                                  'propagate': False, },
                       'django': {'handlers': handler,
                                  'level': level,
                                  'propagate': True, },
                       'django.request': {'handlers': handler,
                                          'level': level,
                                          'propagate': True, }}}
```

Pay attention that the 'db_logger.handlers.DBHandler' points to the handler class.