# Python: flush logging only at end of script run

Tags: python

Currently I use for logging a custom logging system that works as follow:
I have a Log `class` that ressemble the following:

```
class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        self.script = ""
        self.datetime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
        self.mssg = ""
        self.mssg_detail = ""
        self.err = ""
        self.err_detail = ""
```

I created a function decorator that perform a `try/except` on the function call, and add a message either to `.mssg` or `.err` on the `Log` object accordingly.

```
def logging(fun):
    @functools.wraps(fun)
    def inner(self, *args):
        try:
            f = fun(self, *args)
            self.logger.mssg += fun.__name__ +" :ok, "                
            return f               
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.err += fun.__name__ +": error: "+str(e.args) 
    return inner
```

So usually a script is a class that is composed of multiple methods that are run sequentially.
I hence run those methods (decorated such as mentionned above) , and lastly I  upload the Log object into a mysql db.

This works quite fine and alright. But now I want to modify those items so that they integrate with the "official" logging module of python.

What I dont like about that module is that it is not possible to "save" the messages onto 1 log object in order to upload/save to log only at the end of the run. Rather each logging call will write/send the message to a file etc. - which create lots of performances issues sometimes. I could use`handlers.MemoryHandler` , but it still doesn't seems to perform as my original system: it is said to collect messages and flush them to another handler periodically - which is not what i want: I want to collect the messages in memory and to flush them on request with an explicit function.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, you ought to reraise the exception in your decorator.

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE no the whole point is that the script carries on until the end in order to be able to upload the log...

Comment: This is your choice but not a good practice. How do you handle `KeyboardInterrupt`, for instance?

Comment: "But now I want to modify those items so that they integrate with the "official" logging module of python."  What do you mean? Why do this?

Comment: i mean that the expression `self.logger.err += fun.__name__ +": error: "+str(e.args)` etc in the decorator method will be replaced by `logging.error(fun.__name__ +": error: "+str(e.args))` .Similarly the `Log` class declaration will be replaced by a basicConfig logging declaration. I do that because I need to integrate my code with another library that uses the main python logging module.

Comment: Seems to me that you are describing a `StreamHandler`. Have you tried it, perhaps writing to a `StringIO`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler

Comment: @RobertB: `The StreamHandler class, located in the core logging package, sends logging output to streams such as sys.stdout, sys.stderr or any file-like object` (from the doc). I am not interesting to save to file (in fact, its esp. what i want to avoid) so I am not sure what you mean? What I want is to save in memory until he script is done, at which point i save to file / save to mysql db

Comment: "file-like" objects aren't files. `io.StringIO` is "file-like" interface for strings. I posted a detailed answer, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my idea. Use a handler to capture the log in a StringIO. Then you can grab the StringIO whenever you want. Since there was perhaps some confusion in the discussion thread - StringIO is a "file-like" interface for strings, there isn't ever an actual file involved.

```
import logging
import io
def initialize_logging(log_level, log_name='default_logname'):
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)

    log_stream = io.StringIO()

    if not logger.handlers:
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(log_stream)
        ch.setLevel(log_level)
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        ))
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.propagate = 0
    return logger, log_stream
```

And then something like:

```
>>> logger, log_stream = initialize_logging(logging.INFO, "logname")
>>> logger.warning("Hello World!")
```

And when you want the log information:

```
>>> log_stream.getvalue()
'2017-05-16 16:35:03,501 - logname - WARNING - Hello World!\n'
```

Comment: thx a lot. i was wondering - or those LogRecord https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects something that I could use instead of the stringio ?

Comment: I've not looked into it.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

At program start (in the main), you can:

- instanciate your custom logger => global variable/singleton.
- register a function at program end which will flush your logger.
- Run your decorated functions.

To register a function you can use `atexit.register` function. See the page [Exit handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html?highlight=exit#module-atexit) in the doc.

**EDIT**

*The idea above can be simplified.*

To delay the logging, you can use the standard `MemoryHandler` handler, described in the page [logging.handlers — Logging handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler)

Take a look at this GitHub project: https://github.com/tantale/python-ini-cfg-demo

And replace the INI file by this:

```
[formatters]
keys=default

[formatter_default]
format=%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s
class=logging.Formatter

[handlers]
keys=console, alternate

[handler_console]
class=logging.handlers.MemoryHandler
formatter=default
args=(1024, INFO)
target=alternate

[handler_alternate]
class=logging.StreamHandler
formatter=default
args=()

[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
formatter=default
handlers=console
```

To log to a database table, just replace the **alternate** handler by your own database handler.

There is some blog/SO questions about that:

- You can look at [Logging Exceptions To Your SQLAlchemy Database](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/logging/sqlalchemy_logger.html) to create a `SQLAlchemyHandler`
- See [Store Django log to database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11887816/1513933) if you are using DJango.

**EDIT2**

Note: ORM generally support "Eager loading", for instance with [SqlAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading)

Comment: that's an interesting pointers thx! It doesnt answer the main concern of my post (ie I want to get rid of my custom logger and replace it with the python logging utility) but it's definitely something i can use to improve my code.

Comment: If you use a database, you certainly have a cache which you can configure. You can use that with the standard logger.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE  I just gave an answer that answers the specific question. But of course the more obvious answer is the one you site, write a handler that just goes directly to the Database.  I guess the bottom line is... write a handler that does what you want.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Ok thx. I mention `memoryhandler` in my initial post already. The problem is that they are flushed (according to the doc) either when the buffer is full or when an event with a specified level of severity occurs. None of those option are satisfactory to me and i dont know how to circonvene them. I would like to be able to upload all the logs to db explicitely calling a function doing so. btw do you think i could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects ? Just discarding all actual log event, then at exit uploading all the logrecords?

Comment: You could use `MemoryHandler` with a very big size… Yes, you can use `LogRecord` object: it is a simple flat structure.