# how to insert python logs in postgresql table?

Tags: python, postgresql, logging, postgresql-12

I need to insert the logs from my test case into a table in postgresql data base.

I was able to connect to the db but I can't figure out how to insert this line result  in the tabble, I have tried the below but it doesnt work

```
import logging
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO
from config import config
params = config()
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
print(conn)
curr = conn.cursor()
try:

        if not hw.has_connection():
            logging.error('Failure: Unable to reach websb! ==> '+ str(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@jsselect="heading" and @jsvalues=".innerHTML:msg"]').text))

            return

        elif hw.is_websiteReachable():
            logging.info("Success: website is reachable!")

            curr.execute("""INSERT INTO db_name(logs) VALUES (%s)""", ("Success: website is reachable!"))
             conn.commit()
  except:
        logging.error("Failure: Unable to reach website!")
        return
```

Iam a total beginner in this. I have searched but I couldnt find a clear example or guide about it. the above code throws the exception eventhough the website is reachable. sorry if I sound dumb.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're incorrectly constructing your SQL statement. Instead of `INSERT INTO db_name(table_name) ...` it should be `INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) ...`. If you've correctly connected to the appropriate database in your connection settings, you usually don't have to specify the database name each time you write your SQL.

Therefore I would recommend, the following modification (assuming your table is called `logs` and it has a column named `message`):

```py
# ...
sql = 'INSERT INTO logs(message) VALUES (%s);'
msg = 'Success: website is reachable!'
curr.execute(sql, (msg))
conn.commit()
```

You can read the `pyscopg2` docs [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for more information as well if that would help with passing named parameters to your SQL queries in Python.

Comment: Thank you, but Im looking for a way to send the logs from logging directly to the DB, just like the filehandler method but instead to a db

Answer (score 0):

You can check [a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314307/python-logging-to-database/67305494#67305494) that I personally use in my in-server projects. You just need to give a connection-string to the CRUD object and all the things will be done. For Postgres you can use:

```
'postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/database'
```

or

```
'postgresql+pg8000://username:password@host:port/database'
```

for more details check [SQLAlchemy Engine Configuration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html).